# Blocking a specific user from accessing YouTube

Tags: networking, youtube, ipad

I have a D-Link router. I'm trying to block a specific user of the network in question from accessing YouTube, due to the high bandwidth it consumes. My problem is the following: YouTube has so many servers around the world, I literally cannot get every single IP that they use. How can I approach this problem? It's mind-boggling and I need to solve this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: are you the admin on his machine?  also, is he an admin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is asking how to block a user from accessing YouTube on a iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Its non-trivial, but you could run your own caching nameserver with your onw zone set up for Youtube.  (There are a few ways to do this, if your router supports dd-wrt thats a good first step.  You will either want to ensure you can use a different nameserver and he can't or go all in and do split DNS based on your IP !).

That said, instead of trying to prevent him watching Youtube, why not get to the root of the problem - his bandwidth usage.   If you can get dd-wrt (or your router has QoS) built into it, put him in a lower priority bandwidth pool.  This solves the class of problem, rather then encouraging him to switch to another streaming service.

Comment: I'm not sure my router supports that: https://i.gyazo.com/51da345387deb55aef5b0c3e022f168f.png

Also, the administrator is using a macbook air.